# Modifying query to recognize children

Tags: php, mysql

The table gs lists various symbols, most of which are species, such as the bison (gs.Latin = 'Bison-bison'). Each row is also linked to table gw_geog, which has more details on geography, such as the name of each state that adopted the bison as a symbol.

The table gs_planimals is a taxonomic ranking, using a parent-child relationship. The field gs_planimals.Latin includes the value 'Bison-bison," but it also includes its parent, grandparent ('Bovidae') and great grandparent ('Artiodactyla'). However, the rows in gs_planimals include no geographic indicators.

In the following query, GG.IDParent = 'afr' selects rows whose parents are 'afr' (Africa). So it displays a list of symbols adopted by African countries.

```
SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.Planimal, PLAN.Family, PLAN.Order1, PLAN.NoSymbol, PLAN.National, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GG.URL AS GURL, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"',  GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>')) AS Names, GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea AND GG.IDParent = 'afr'
WHERE Rank != 55 AND PLAN.National = 'nat' AND NoSymbol != '1'
GROUP BY PLAN.Latin
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

The problem is that it only works on the species level (symbols or species stored in table gs). Higher taxa (e.g. families and orders) are derived from table gs_planimals. Since that table has no geographic clues, it displays ALL families and orders, wether they're the grandparents of a particular symbolic species or not.

In other word, I do NOT want to display this:

```
Carnivora
Canidae
Felidae
Artiodactyla
Bovidae
Cervidae
Bison-bison
```

I instead want to display this:

```
Artiodactyla
Bovidae
Bison-bison
```

So here's my question: Is there a way to modify my query (or add a script) so that families (`gs_planimals.Latin`) that have no children in table gs aren't displayed, and orders (`gs_planimals.Latin`) that have no families as children in this particular query similarly aren't displayed?

**Edit: Data**

There are eight fields that are most important. Tables gs and gw_geog each have a field named IDArea, on which they're joined. Tables gs and gs_planimals are joined on a field named Latin. The field gs.Symbol is a little redundant; it's essentially the same as the field gs_planimals.Common.

Most symbolic plants and animals are species, represented by Rank = 65 in the table gs_planimals. However, gs_planimals also includes higher taxons, such as families and orders.

Most of the other fields are qualifiers used to select particular groups of plants or animals (e.g. mammals) or particular regions (e.g. North America).

If we display a list of North American mammal symbols, it would include the bison (the United States' national animal and a symbol of several states as well) and bighorn sheep but not the African lion. It would also include the bison/bighorn sheep's grandparents (families) and great grandparents (orders). So it would look like this:

Order Artiodactyla
Family Bovidae
bison (Bison bison) | United States, Kansas, Wyoming
bighorn sheep (Ovis canadensis) | Alberta, Colorado

A query displaying all ecosymbols (plants and animals both) representing South American countries looks like this:

```
SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.Planimal, PLAN.NoSymbol, PLAN.National, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GG.URL AS GURL, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"', GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>') ORDER BY GG.Name SEPARATOR ', ') AS Names,  GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea AND GG.IDParent = 'sa'
WHERE Rank != 55 AND PLAN.National = 'nat' AND NoSymbol != '1'
GROUP BY PLAN.Latin
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

IDParent = 'sa' indicates that nothing is selected from the table gw_geog unless its parent is 'sa' (South America). NoSymbol simply weeds out a few errors in my database table.

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. The whole point of `LEFT JOIN` is that it includes rows in the left table that have no match in the right table. But you only want rows that DO have a match.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. The problem is that values in gs_planimals above the species level don't have any matches. As far as I know, the only way I can instruct my query to not include certain values is to say "This value doesn't have a child in the flow, so don't display it." But it's possible that what I'm trying to do can't be done; I may have to redesign my tables and queries. Thx.

Comment: It certainly can be done, we just need to look closer at the data. Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do that now... I may have to get back to this tomorrow after work. ;)

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da19 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8

Comment: There's nothning in the second fiddle. You should put all the tables in one fiddle.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/892ba However, I won't be able to revisit this discussion until tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: Need some DATA in there, not just the schemas.

Comment: Please don't post a description of the data, post the actual data as a table, e.g. the output of `SELECT * FROM gs_planimals`, `SELECT * FROM gs` and `SELECT * FROM gw_geog`. I can't help you if I don't have data that I can perform queries against, and I'm not going to type the data by hand.

Comment: How are these?

http://www.geobop.org/test/test-gs.php

http://www.geobop.org/test/test-gs-planimals.php

http://www.geobop.org/test/test-gw-geog.php